# Manipulate combobox using dictionary in java

Tags: java, wcf, web-services, dictionary, combobox

I am consuming a web service which is returning me result of type "ArrayOfKeyValueOfintstring"

I am confused how to add this data to my combo box in java.

Here is my code

```
 org.tempuri.ThirdPartyService service = new org.tempuri.ThirdPartyService();
 org.tempuri.IThirdPartyService port = service.getBasicHttpBindingIThirdPartyService();
 // TODO initialize WS operation arguments here
 java.lang.String key = line.trim();
 // TODO process result here
 String>)port.getTests(key).getKeyValueOfintstring();
 com.microsoft.schemas._2003._10.serialization.arrays.ArrayOfKeyValueOfintstring result = port.getVulnerabilities(key);
```

**EDIT**

```
for(int i=0;i<=result.getKeyValueOfintstring().size();i++)
{
   result.getKeyValueOfintstring().get(i).getKey();
   result.getKeyValueOfintstring().get(i).getValue();
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "key is"+result.getKeyValueOfintstring().get(i).getKey());
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Value is"+result.getKeyValueOfintstring().get(i).getValue());
   model.addElement(new Item(key, value));

 }
```

I have tried to get the key pair in dialog box and i got it correctly. But now i am not getting how to add them to my ComboBox. I have created table  "Vector model = new Vector();" and adding it to the combo box like this "cbTestName = new JComboBox(model);"

Is it the correct way or do i need to apply anything else to add the key value pair to my combo box.

Answer (score 0):

If you'll go to declaration of

`port.getTests(key).getKeyValueOfintstring()`,

you'll probably find its implemented as

```
List<KeyValuePairOfintstring>
```

and `KeyValuePairOfintstring` is looks like

```
...

    protected Integer key;
...  
    protected String value;
```

So one of the ways you can do - is run over `port.getTests(key).getKeyValueOfintstring()` in the loop, and build your map with your java business objects, you want to display in Combo Box.

You can override your object's toString method as a simplest way to control how will they look in the ComboBox.

Comment: here key i am passing as argument is my authentication key, not the one from "key value" pair

Comment: Did you review getKeyValueOfintstring() declaration?